# Как выбрать необходимую строку из таблицы в отношении many-to-many?

Tags: sql, join, many-to-many

Есть три таблицы в отношении many-to-many.

address (id, name), group (group_id, group_name), и address_in_groups (id, group_id).

В одной группе может быть несколько адресов. Но количество адресов в группе не может превышать общее количество адресов.

Необходимо найти группу, в которой ещё есть свободное место.

Comment: Многие ко многим у вас как раз реализовано через третью таблицу. Просто выведите их через `JOIN`ы.

Comment: Вроде бы отрабатывает через: 

SELECT group_id FROM group

LEFT JOIN address_in_groups ON group.group_id = address_in_groups.group_id

GROUP BY group.group_id

HAVING COUNT(address_in_groups.id) < (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM address)

Comment: *Необходимо найти группу, в которой ещё есть свободное место.* Иными словами, найти такую пару группа+адрес, которой ещё нет в таблице связи. По-моему, совершенно тривиальная задача. `address CROSS JOIN group LEFT JOIN junction WHERE IS NULL`